# pass string variable as a table name in an SQL query

Tags: c++, mysql, sql, c, sqlite

My program takes in a string as a parameter, and attempts to create a table in an SQL database with the passed string parameter as the name of the table.

I have experience with SQL, but I'm new when it comes to implementing it in C++.

```
class logger {
public:
    string name;                //name of application to be logged
    
    logger(string app) {
        //open data base and get handle for future queries 
        
        name = app;
        sqlite3 *db;
        char *zErrMsg = 0;
        int rc;
        char *sql;

        rc = sqlite3_open("@name", &db);
    
        if( rc ){
            fprintf(stderr, "Can't open database: %s\n", sqlite3_errmsg(db));
            sqlite3_close(db);
        }

        sql = "create table if not exists" + name + "(timestamp varchar(255), message varchar(255));"
        
        rc = sqlite3_exec(db, sql, callback, 0, &zErrMsg);
        
        if( rc != SQLITE_OK ){
            fprintf(stderr, "SQL error: %s\n", zErrMsg);
            sqlite3_free(zErrMsg);
        } else {
            fprintf(stdout, "Table created successfully\n");
        }
        
        sqlite3_close(db);
    }
};
```

Error:

```
logger.cpp:29:52: error: cannot convert ‘std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>’ to ‘char*’ in assignment
   29 |         sql = "create table if not exists " + name + "(timestamp varchar(255), message varchar(255));"
      |               ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
      |                                                    |
      |                                                    std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>
```

Comment: Add a space after `if not exists`.

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/

Comment: `sql` is a `char*`, you are attempting to assign a `string` to it ... The error you get is unrelated to SQL, and is just simple C++ error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't build a C string the same way you build a C++ `std::string`.

Instead, make `sql` be a `std::string`, build the string, then use its `c_str()` method to get a C string pointer from it.

```
string sql;
...
rc = sqlite3_exec(db, sql.c_str(), callback, 0, &zErrMsg);
```